# How to use AngularJS date filter with a string that has a date

Tags: angularjs, date, angular-date-format

I have the following files.

**index.js**

```
...
completedTooltip = 'Completed on 2019-02-02T23:59:59-07:00';
...
```

**index.html**

```
...
{{completedTooltip | date : 'MM/dd/yyyy'}}
...
```

The date doesn't get formatted here and just spits out the string.

Is there any way I can make this work `OR` do I have to just have 2 separate vars so that one var can hold the text and the other can hold the date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create custom filter,

```
app.filter("anyName", function($filter) {
  return function(input, format) {
    var txtArr = input.split(' ');
    txtArr[2] = $filter('date')(txtArr[2], format);
    return txtArr.join(' ');
  };
});
```

And use that in your HTML

```
{{completedTooltip | anyName : 'MM/dd/yyyy'}}
```